# jquery - I need to clean up and merge my code

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code on my website to show and hide page content dependent on different button clicks.

The page layout is

```
button | button2
section
content
content2
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //Hide all content to be revealed
  $('.reveal_content').hide();

  //Create the click event for each reveal button
  $('.reveal_button').click(function(e) {

    //Prevent the default button action (i.e. redirecting to a url)
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the parent section for the button clicked
    $parent_section = $(this).closest('.reveal_section');

    //Remove the opened class from all other buttons
    $('.reveal_button').not(this).removeClass('opened');

    //Close all content in other sections
    $('.reveal_section').not($parent_section).find('.reveal_content').fadeOut('slow');

    //Hide/Reveal the content in the same section as the button clicked
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $parent_section.find('.reveal_content').each(function() {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    })

  });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //Hide all content to be revealed
  $('.reveal_content2').hide();

  //Create the click event for each reveal button
  $('.reveal_button2').click(function(e) {

    //Prevent the default button action (i.e. redirecting to a url)
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the parent section for the button clicked
    $parent_section = $(this).closest('.reveal_section');

    //Remove the opened class from all other buttons
    $('.reveal_button2').not(this).removeClass('opened');

    //Close all content in other sections
    $('.reveal_section').not($parent_section).find('.reveal_content2').fadeOut('slow');

    //Hide/Reveal the content in the same section as the button clicked
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $parent_section.find('.reveal_content2').each(function() {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    })

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_2 reveal_section et_section_regular">
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_2 et_pb_row_4col">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_3  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_0_wrapper  et_pb_module ">
                <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 reveal_button et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="">Walton-on-Thames</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_4  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_1_wrapper  et_pb_module ">
                <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_1 reveal_button2 et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="">Bury St Edmunds</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_3 reveal_content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_7  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_1 star-star  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <h1>Walton-on-Thames</h1>
                    <p>Our walks take place on the first Saturday of every month, at 9am. We meet at Cowey Sale car park
                        (Walton Lane- KT12 1QW). Cafe and toilet facilities are available.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_4 reveal_content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_5 et_pb_column_8  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_2 star-star  et_pb_text_align_center et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <h1>Contact us to book your FREE space</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_5 reveal_content2" style="display: none;">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_10  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_6  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <h1>Bury St Edmunds</h1>
                    <p>Our walks take place on the XX XXday of every month, at XXam. We meet at Nowton Park, Nowton
                        Road, Bury St Edmunds, IP29 5LU. Cafe and toilet facilities are avaliable.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_6 reveal_content2" style="display: none;">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_5 et_pb_column_11  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7 star-star  et_pb_text_align_center et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <h1>Contact us to book your FREE space</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but is there a way to merge the code in to one script at all and can I hide 'reveal_content' when it shows 'reveal_content2' and hide 'reveal_content2' if im showing 'reveal_content'.

I've tried copying the code and just pasting the lines under each other but it stopped working, so I'm guessing there is a way to have them together?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well. It's much more difficult to help you debug when can't see/don't have the elements you are actually working with. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor - Sorry, this is a full [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/TridentMarketingUK/t81L3w9o/2/)

Comment: I put your code into a snippet and trimmed a bunch of the HTML (the map, contact form) as it wasn't necessary for the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a challenge because Divi doesn't allow you to add attributes or really anything meaningful to the code to allow you to target elements easily.

What this code does (so it's scalable, you'll have to make some changes to your CSS classes in Divi):

1. The buttons only have the class `reveal_button` - no need to get more specific.
2. Each row that needs to be controlled by a specific button has an incrementing `reveal_content_x` and `reveal_content` classes, e.g. the first button opens two rows, so those rows have a `reveal_content_1` and a `reveal_content` class.
3. For each button, the JS adds a `data-reveal` attribute with a value to match the content section it needs to open, so the first button "Walton on the Thames" gets the value of `reveal_content_1` (this is how we control the button's targets)
4. On document load, all content sections are closed.
5. The rest of the JS is commented to show what it's doing.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Set the reveal_content rows to a let/variable.
  let reveal_content = $('.reveal_content'),
    // Set the buttons to a let/variable
    reveal_buttons = $('.reveal_button');

  //Hide all content to be revealed on document ready.
  reveal_content.hide();

  // For each button let's do some stuff.
  reveal_buttons.each(function(index) {

    // Adds a data-attribute to the button to match the class of the reveal content row. The index is being increment by one + one to avoid the reveal_content_0 class.
    this.dataset.reveal = 'reveal_content_' + (index + 1);

    // On the button click.
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {

      //Prevent the default button action.
      e.preventDefault();

      // Remove the open class on ALL buttons
      reveal_buttons.each(function() {
        this.classList.remove('opened');
      });

      // Toggle the opened class on the clicked button.
      $(this).toggleClass('opened');

      // Get ALL of the reveal_content rows that have a class that matches the data-reveal of the button.
      let selected_reveal_content = $('.' + this.dataset.reveal);

      // Close/hide ALL of the rows.
      reveal_content.hide();

      // Show all of the rows that match the class/data-reveal
      selected_reveal_content.fadeToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.opened {
/* This is just to have a visual cue */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_2 reveal_section et_section_regular">
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_2 et_pb_row_4col">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_3  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
      <div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_0_wrapper  et_pb_module ">
        <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 reveal_button et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="">Walton-on-Thames</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_4  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
      <div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_1_wrapper  et_pb_module ">
        <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_1 reveal_button et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="">Bury St Edmunds</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_3 reveal_content reveal_content_1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_7  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_1 star-star  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h1>Walton-on-Thames</h1>
          <p>Our walks take place on the first Saturday of every month, at 9am. We meet at Cowey Sale car park (Walton Lane- KT12 1QW). Cafe and toilet facilities are available.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_4 reveal_content reveal_content_1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_5 et_pb_column_8  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_2 star-star  et_pb_text_align_center et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h1>Contact us to book your FREE space</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_5 reveal_content reveal_content_2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_10  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_6  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h1>Bury St Edmunds</h1>
          <p>Our walks take place on the XX XXday of every month, at XXam. We meet at Nowton Park, Nowton Road, Bury St Edmunds, IP29 5LU. Cafe and toilet facilities are avaliable.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_6 reveal_content reveal_content_2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_5 et_pb_column_11  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7 star-star  et_pb_text_align_center et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h1>Contact us to book your FREE space</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```